# How to get remote controlled raspberry pi to play music/video out of its OWN speakers

Tags: networking, streaming-video, hard-drive, media-server, file-sharing

In the past I have in the past created a NAS which I can use to play music through my PC or phone. I would, now like to make a media centre with a raspberry pi (B rev 2) which will be able to play video through my TV, and control this with my phone, preferably through a website as I do not have much storage on my phone.

I would store the video in a hard drive connected via USB.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this are welcome.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I wonder just a little, your title reads "play music" your question asks about "video" twice. What's what now? If it really is video I don't see how `Kodi` would not be your friend.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error I have changed it now and Kodi does  look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to bring up [Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) as a tool to play audio as I found it easy to set up und it's running well on the Pi.

With extensions it allows you to stream from cloud services (if the Pi would be online) such as Spotify as well as local files. It can be controlled by a multitude of clients (local or remote; command line, graphical, web based, android apps). Packages for installation are available for Debian and Arch Linux, but other than that it can be installed from source and is running on python2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838501/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-audio-streaming-box), I used it and it is great.
I don't know if it supports video though.

If video is more important, try using [this](https://osmc.tv).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, video is more important so I will try OMSC.